# Finding $\{x \mid x^2-7x+10=0, x \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just need a clear explanation of this because I am thinking should it be $x(x - 10) -7= 0$, i.e., $x = \{7,10\}$

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: did you mean to ask whether the solutions of $x^2-7x+10 = 0$ are natural numbers?

Comment: Your title and question do not match.  Title has "$-7x$", question has $-10 x$.  What is the purpose of the symbols "$x/$" near the beginning of the title?

Comment: Note that $x(x - 10) - 7 = x^2 - 10x - 7$.  You need to factor $x^2 - 7x + 10$ into linear factors $(x - m)(x - n)$.  Try multiplying $(x - m)(x - n)$ to see how to express $-7$ and $10$ in terms of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Have you just tried $7$ and $10$?  Do they work?

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2-7x+10=0 \implies x^2-5x-2x+10=0 \implies x(x-5)-2(x-5)=0 \implies (x-5)(x-2)=0
\implies x=5~or~2.$$

Answer (score 1):

I am curious to know how you got from:

$x^2 - 7x + 10  = 0$ to $x(x-10) + 7 = 0$

I could see how you might arrive at $x(x-7) + 10 = 0$

and then you went from:

$x(x-10) + 7 = 0$ to $x = \{7,10\}$

Plugging 7 and 10 in the equation to the left gives, $-14$ and $7$ respectively.

Factoring is soul of algebra.

What we are looking for are two "roots" i.e. $a,b$ such that $(x-a)(x-b) = 0$

And this way, if $x = a$ or $x=b$ then one factor will equal zero.  Which means that the whole thing equals zero.  How do we find this $a,b$?

We need $ab = 10$ and $a+b = -7$  And since it is given that we only care about solutions in $\mathbb N$ the best place to start is with the factors of $10.$

We can only factor 10 two ways $(1)(10), (2)(5).$  And only one of these pairs sums to $7.$

$(x-2)(x-5) = x^2 - 7x + 10 = 0$

Our solution set is $x\in\{2,5\}$

Comment: O my God thanks alot It skip off my mind thanks once again